# Discord python How to programm a ping command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So i'm trying to programm a ping command via python and discord. The problem is, that after trying a bunch of methods, i still don't know how it works. I would be very thankful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord
import time

from time import 
time_then = time.monotonic()
pinger = await client.send_message(message.channel, '__*`Pinging...`*__')
ping = '%.2f' % (1000*(time.monotonic()-time_then))
await client.edit_message(pinger, ':ping_pong: \n **Pong!** __**`' + ping + 'ms`**__') # you can edit this to say whatever you want really. Hope this helps.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using discord.py rewrite with commands extension you can `bot.latency` which returns a float.